# Does it make sense to select SARIMAX parameters independently of covariates?

Tags: time-series, arima, feature-selection

I have a vector of time series observations $y$ and a matrix of covariates $X$. I want to choose the best (in the sense of minimizing loss function, e.g. RMSE) $SARIMAX(p,d,q)×(P,D,Q)_{s}$ model specification by performing both grid search on parameters and exhaustive feature selection on covariates. However, it is very computationally costly to do simultaneously (i.e. going through every possible covariates combination and performing grid search for parameters for each).

Question is: does it make sense to first choose $SARIMAX$ parameters and then perform feature selection on covariates? Can one miss the best (in a sense described earlier) model by a large margin this way?

Comment: There are lag orders $p$, $q$ etc. (they could perhaps be called hyperparameters) and there are parameters of the SARIMAX equation ($\varphi_1$, $\theta_1$, $\Phi_1$, $\Theta_1$, ...). When you say *parameters*, do you mean lag orders here?

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. I mean hyperparameters $(p,d,q)×(P,D,Q)_{s}$ (so, lag orders and difference orders both for ARIMA and seasonal component).

Comment: Thank for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as they are in general not uncorrelated since the simple arima structure was premised that the X's didn't explicitely have an effect on Y  . One needs to in one way or another to determine the best combination GIVEN of course that pulses, level/step shifts, seasonal pulses, local time trends  (the I's in this image https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf ) are also in the mix while a suitable power transform ( possibly 1.0) is in effect.

The answer to your last question is Yes you can miss the boat by not simultaneously identifying all needed (statistically necessary) structure via schemes like this https://autobox.com/pdfs/A.pdf without over-fitting